# How to validate an SMPS transformer?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, full-bridge

From UCC28950 webench design data I have approached a vendor for making a transformer for Phase shifted Full Bridge DC -DC converter. Now before giving order to vendor, I want to gather data on how to make an SMPS transformer and How to validate it.

Comment: Has the company making the transformer got a good reputation in building transformers of the type you require. That should be the first thing to address.

Comment: You need a lot more information than that. What is your input voltage, output voltage, output current? What are your size limitations? What is your power loss budget? What is your switching frequency? Are you using a bridge rectifier or a current doubler on the output? HF Transformer design is very iterative.

Comment: what @Stiddily said: you've got a design from the Webbench thingie. Great! so you've already got a detailed simulation of what to expect.

Comment: Yes marcus. I got enough information on the transformer. That is why I have provided data to the vendor and they have agreed to make it.

Comment: @Andy, I don't know much about that company, based upon user reviews i have chosen that company. I just want to make sure whether the transformer is accurate as per the application or not ? Because I don't want any loose ends.

Comment: @stiddily, Actually the parameters you have said, like input output voltage, switching frequency etc. are fixed and non customisable, as the tool webench provided by TI will take your requirements i.e. Input voltage, Output voltage, and power rating of the converter and create one design with their available controller ICs for the listed parameters before. So I have provided the exact details to the vendor.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware WebBench was that detailed... I got confused with the "I want to gather data on how to make an SMPS transformer" part of your question.

Comment: So can you provide me any reference on how to validate the SMPS transformer or any book in which it is listed